# Trigger.io 's main activity

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, trigger.io

Does anyone know what is the main activity we should use when setting up a Facebook application that uses Trigger.io on Android?

I guess it should be MainActivity but I'm not 100% sure.

This is what FB is asking me for:

http://screencast.com/t/AIN4rm5Su[image: FB App config]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `AndroidManifest.xml` file from the Trigger.io build process, you should take the name of your default activity:

> io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity

It is the same for every app build via Trigger.io, but that's okay.